# some part of image is blacked in oneplus 3t device in android custom camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

Hi I am facing a weird issue. I am using custom camera in my app, It is working fine in all other devices except oneplus 3t.

the issue is image is not getting saved as half blacked

I am using this [camera fragment](https://github.com/florent37/CameraFragment)]

please help to solve this 
attaching screen shots for better understanding of the question[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: What is 1 +3t ?

Comment: oneplus 3t device